# Get row count before LIMIT but on it's own row

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to get the full row count before i limit the return in postgres, which I have using:

```
count(*) OVER() AS full_count
```

However as I put it in the select it outputs it with every row which is less then ideal. I'm outputting it in `NodeJS` as `JSON` and noticed that the output contains it's own tow with `rowCount`, but this is after the limit, is there a way to replace the `rowCount` in the `JSON` with `full_count`, or a better way of trying to do what I'm doing? This is my query thus far:

```
SELECT name, id, count(*) OVER() AS full_count FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ($1) OFFSET ($2)
```

**Update**

Expected output:

```
{
  total : 170000
  rows : [
    {
      name : Karl,
      age : 31,
    },
      name : Helen,
      age : 36
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update 2**

NodeJS

***Route***

```
router.get('/api/v1/person/:limit?/:offset?', (req, res, next) => { 
    person.get(req, res);
});
```

***Model***

```
this.get = function(req, res) {        
    var limit = req.params.person_limit || 10;
    var offset = req.params.person_offset || 0;
    if (limit > 100) {
        limit = 100;
    }
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            done();
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
        }
        client.query('SELECT name, id FROM person ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ($1) OFFSET ($2)',[limit, offset], function(err, result) {
          done();             
          if(err) {
              return console.error('error running query', err);
          } 
          res.send(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Write an example of what you expect from your query.

Comment: @pietrop hi thanks for the reply I have added my expected outcome.

Comment: Write also your Node.js code

Comment: @pietrop I have added my route and my model, hopefully this helps to see what I'm trying to achieve.